# autoref without space

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, autoref

I want to reference sections in the form '§1'. I use [hyperref.sty](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), and I have changed the sectionautorefname: `\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{\S}`. This prints '§ 1', with a space. Can I remove the space?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{\S}
\begin{document}
\section{section}
\label{section}
\autoref{section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `\kern` it to the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{\S\kern-4pt}
\begin{document}
\section{section}
\label{section}
\autoref{section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps a better way is to gobble the space:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{\S\@gobble}
\makeatother
```

though I don't know if this latter approach has any unintended pitfalls.

Comment: I needed `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to do `\@gobble`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8353/451

Comment: @twsh Yes you do...I should have mentioned that.